# Is there any way to unit test a Mapstruct with nested Mapper?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, mapstruct

I'm trying to unit test a Mapstruct nested mapper as follows:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = EventCategoryMapper.class, injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR)
public interface EventMapper {

    
    Event fromEventMO(EventMO eventMO);

    EventMO toEventMO(Event event);

    default Optional<Event> fromOptionalEventMO(Optional<EventMO> optionalEventMO) {
        
        return (optionalEventMO.isEmpty()) ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(fromEventMO(optionalEventMO.get()));
        
    }
    
}
```

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR)
public interface EventCategoryMapper {

    
    EventCategory fromEventCategoryMO(EventCategoryMO eventCategoryMO);

    EventCategoryMO toEventCategoryMO(EventCategory eventCategory);

    default String fromPriorityMO(PriorityMO priority) {
        return (priority.getPriority()==null) ? null : priority.getPriority();
    }
```

I'm trying to test the EventMapper:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {EventMapper.class, EventCategoryMapper.class, EventMapperImpl.class, EventCategoryMapperImpl.class})
public class EventMapperTest {

    private Mocks mocks; //This object contains the mocked objects that should be mapped.

    @Autowired
    private EventMapper eventMapper;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should return an Event from an EventMO")
    void shouldReturnEventfromEventMO() {
        
        var event = eventMapper.fromEventMO(mocks.getEventMO());

        assertEquals(event.getId(), 123L);


    }
```

But it keeps failing with:

> Error creating bean with name 'eventMapper': Instantiation of bean
> failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate
> [com.mycompany.cna.projects.fishmarket.back.events.repositories.mappers.event.EventMapper]:
> Specified class is an interface

I've already tried instantiating the mapper with Mapper.getMapper(EventMapper.class) and it returned a NullPointerException.

What should I do to achieve unit testing on those kind of mappers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this. The problem was that I wasn't instantiating my Mocks object. I've also provided a mock of the nested mapper to the EventMapperImpl in the before method:

```
    @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class EventMapperTest {

    private Mocks mocks;

    private EventMapper eventMapper;

    @Mock
    private EventCategoryMapper eventCategoryMapper;

    @BeforeEach
    void before() {
        eventMapper = new EventMapperImpl(eventCategoryMapper);
        mocks = new Mocks();
    }
    
    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should return an Event from an EventMO")
    void shouldReturnEventfromEventMO() {

        when(eventCategoryMapper.fromEventCategoryMO(any(EventCategoryMO.class))).thenReturn(mocks.getEventCategory());
        var event = eventMapper.fromEventMO(mocks.getEventMO());

        assertEquals(event.getId(), 123L);


    }
```